# Почему numpy append не добавляет элемент в массив?

Tags: python, numpy

```
array = np.array(train["text"][0])
    for i in range(1, len(train["text"])):
        np.append(array, train["text"][i], axis = 0)
```

Series train["text"] выглядит так(его часть):

```
  0      [254, 5, 46, 1, 39, 1, 32, 1, 7, 4, 5, 1, 13, ...
1      [254, 32, 85, 30, 1, 1, 85, 43, 2, 12, 144, 27...
2      [112, 14, 20, 254, 88, 124, 254, 10, 39, 112, ...
3      [111, 5, 14, 85, 55, 5, 4, 9, 5, 85, 3, 27, 14...
4      [111, 16, 144, 58, 17, 10, 18, 39, 3, 8, 1, 23...
                             ...                        
289    [55, 10, 79, 4, 14, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 40, 1, 2...
290    [25, 68, 50, 43, 191, 111, 191, 50, 43, 124, 2...
291    [55, 8, 29, 13, 32, 85, 1, 27, 3, 13, 29, 4, 2...
292     [36, 7, 254, 40, 30, 37, 85, 6, 1, 7, 1, 86, 72]
293    [30, 51, 124, 55, 30, 51, 39, 47, 10, 2, 30, 5...
Name: text, Length: 294, dtype: object
```

После цикла я получаю тот же массив, что и задал в начале в переменной array:

```
[254   5  46   1  39   1  32   1   7   4   5   1  13   2 124   1   2   5
 254   5  39   3   1   1  29   2  32   1  40   1  12   3  39   3   5 112
  88 124  30   4  14  17   1  44  86   4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что в [документации](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) написано:

> Returns : ndarray
> A **copy** of arr with values appended to `axis`. Note that append does not occur in-place: **a new array is allocated and filled**. If axis is None, out is a flattened array.

В вашем случае нужно писать

`array = np.append(array, train["text"][i], axis = 0)`

Но есть вариант быстрее. Если вам нужно склеить все массивы в один длинный, воспользуйтесь [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). Если нужно сделать двумерный массив из набора одномерных, то [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) (но в этом случае все массивы должны быть одной длины)

Answer (score 0):

По идее вам вообще цикл не нужен, при условии, что длина всех списков в колонке одинаковая, учитесь работать со всем датафреймом сразу, это гораздо быстрее, чем итерироваться по строкам:

```
array = np.vstack(train['text'])
```